# Disable www.mywebsite.com/index.php/route access

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

My website can be view from 2 different kind of URI:

[www.mywebsite.com/magazine](http://www.mywebsite.com/magazine) or [www.mywebsite.com/index.php/magazine](http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php/magazine)

It makes a copy of my website which is very bad for Google SEO. Someone have any idea how to disable the index.php browsing?

This is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `mod_rewrite` to write a `RewriteRule` to do a permanent redirect from /index.php/magazine to /magazine.

**EDIT 5/21/11 9:40am EST**
After some "quick" testing, I realized that the below rule won't work if youre trying to apply it to a sub-folder in your document root (eg: www.mysite.com/test/index.php/go/somewhere).  This is because of the way `mod_rewrite` works, which is documented on the [Apache `mod_rewrite` Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and says that:

> **Note: Pattern matching in per-directory context**
>
> Never forget that Pattern is applied
>   to a complete URL in per-server
>   configuration files. **However, in
>   per-directory configuration files, the
>   per-directory prefix (which always is
>   the same for a specific directory) is
>   automatically removed for the pattern
>   matching and automatically added after
>   the substitution has been done**. This
>   feature is essential for many sorts of
>   rewriting - without this, you would
>   always have to match the parent
>   directory which is not always
>   possible. There is one exception: If a
>   substitution string starts with
>   '`http://`', then the directory prefix
>   will not be added, and an external
>   redirect or proxy throughput (if flag
>   **P** is used) is forced!

So, if your `.htaccess` file is within a sub-directory, your `RewriteRule` becomes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/.*)$ /sub-dir-name$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Otherwise, if you're rewriting from the root of the domain, it is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php(/.*)$ /$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Hope that works for you!

Comment: Thank you, it's what i'm looking for but it's seem not easy to find the good syntax

Comment: Thank you but it did not work, i put my htaccess file on my post.

Comment: this would go under the `RewriteEngine On` directive, but before everything else.

Comment: This is what i did but it's not work. This code work for you ?

Comment: @Jim Rubenstein: Why do you need the `RewriteCond` at all? Couldn't you just use the `RewriteRule` alone? In fact, how about this: `RewriteRule ^index\.php(/.*)$ $1 [R=301,QSA,L]`?

Comment: edited, and has more information explaining a caveat of `mod_rewrite`

Comment: Thank you. My htaccess is not on sub directory your code working now, just have to delete "/" charac and its ok

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^index.php(/.*)$ $1 [R=301,QSA,L]